# number_format() with MySQL

Tags: mysql

hey i need a way to get a formated number from my column `decimal(23,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'`

in php i could use this function `number_format('1111.00', 2, ',', '.');`
it would return `1.111,00` (in Germany we use , to define decimal numbers)

how would i do this in mysql? with string replaces?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

http://blogs.mysql.com/peterg/2009/04/

In Mysql 6.1 you will be able to do FORMAT(X,D [,locale_name] )

As in

```
 SELECT format(1234567,2,’de_DE’);
```

For now this ability does not exist, though you MAY be able to set your locale in your database my.ini check it out.

Comment: oi I tried to use the locale param and now find it only exist in MySQL 6. Thank you about the info.

Comment: Unfortunately the third parameter is illegal in MariaDB 5.5.x

Comment: Here is the list of locale https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html

Answer (score 23):

With performance penalty and if you need todo it only in SQL you can use the  [`FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function and 3 `REPLACE` :
After the format replace the `.` with another char for example `@`, then replace the `,` with a `.` and then the chararacter you choose by a `,` which lead you for your example to `1.111,00`

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(FORMAT("1111.00", 2), ".", "@"), ",", "."), "@", ",")
```

Comment: ok i think im gonna stick with the php way, thx for you answer anyway

Comment: This is not the best answer! There is the format function available, scroll down and have a look at some of the other answers before using this solution - the important thing to note here is the LOCALE option available to the `format` function that you can set (e,g, de_DE for german)

Answer (score 14):

You can use

```
SELECT round(123.4566,2)  -> 123.46
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is the thousands separator,

    SELECT round(123456,2) -> 123456.00

Answer (score 7):

FORMAT(X,D) Formats the number X to a format like '#,###,###.##', rounded to D decimal places, and returns the result as a string. If D is 0, the result has no decimal point or fractional part.

```
 SELECT FORMAT(12332.123456, 4);
        -> '12,332.1235'
```

Answer (score 3):

Antonio's answer

```
CONCAT(REPLACE(FORMAT(number,0),',','.'),',',SUBSTRING_INDEX(FORMAT(number,2),'.',-1))
```

is wrong; it may produce incorrect results!

For example, if "number" is 12345.67, the resulting string would be:

```
'12.346,67'
```

instead of

```
'12.345,67'
```

because FORMAT(number,0) rounds "number" up if fractional part is greater or equal than 0.5 (as it is in my example)!

What you COULD use is

```
CONCAT(REPLACE(FORMAT(FLOOR(number),0),',','.'),',',SUBSTRING_INDEX(FORMAT(number,2),'.',-1))
```

if your MySQL/MariaDB's FORMAT doesn't support "locale_name" (see MindStalker's post - Thx 4 that, pal). Note the FLOOR function I've added.

Answer (score 3):

At least as far back as MySQL 5.5 you can use format:

```
SELECT FORMAT(123456789.123456789,2);
/* produces 123,456,789.12 */

SELECT FORMAT(123456789.123456789,2,'de_DE');
/* 
    produces 123.456.789,12
    note the swapped . and , for the de_DE locale (German-Germany) 
*/
```

From the MySQL docs: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format

Available locales are listed elsewhere in the docs:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/locale-support.html

Comment: thanks, easy way to fix number_format from MySQL => client

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`yourfunctionname`@`%` FUNCTION `money`(
     `betrag` DECIMAL(10,2)

 )
 RETURNS varchar(128) CHARSET latin1
 LANGUAGE SQL
 NOT DETERMINISTIC
 CONTAINS SQL
 SQL SECURITY DEFINER
 COMMENT ''
 return(
     select replace(format(cast(betrag as char),2),',',"'") as betrag
 )
```

will creating a MySql-Function with this Code:

```
 select replace(format(cast(amount as char),2),',',"'") as amount_formated
```

Answer (score -1):

You need this:

```
CONCAT(REPLACE(FORMAT(number,0),',','.'),',',SUBSTRING_INDEX(FORMAT(number,2),'.',-1))
```

Comment: This solution may cause wrong results! See answer from eyebeebai.